# Sort views exposed filter in drupalgap alphabetically

Tags: views, javascript

Despite trying to make it work at all posible ways, i'm not able to order the select/options form from A to Z. it displays me by option "id" and what i want is to show my drupalgap form using hook_form_alter and display the order correctly. This is the last thing i tried until now. Thanks!!!

```
 $(document).on("pageload", "#informes", function() {
      console.log("hola");
        $("#edit-views-exposed-form-field-organismo-auditado-mobile-value").append($("#edit-views-exposed-form-field-organismo-auditado-mobile-value option").remove().sort(function(a, b) {
            var at = $(a).text(), bt = $(b).text();
            return (at > bt)?1:((at < bt)?-1:0);
        }));
      });
```

Comment: Do a `console.log(form.elements['field_organismo_auditado_mobile_value']);`, what does that report? Please use pastebin (or something).

Comment: I did it so what i have to apply is a function... like the one i edited in the topic. The problem is that the console.log works but not the function. When i put the function into the console it works!!! i don't know how to make it work when the page load!!!

Comment: Maybe try the 'pageshow' event and make sure you're including your JS like this: http://www.drupalgap.org/node/531

Comment: I implemented everything the drupalgap site said, like the script in the html and the pageshow event. But anything seems to work, i have now a clean code but it's necessary that the arguments of the hook form alter pass the parameters to the other function. To know what i mean i will post the code in fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/1wd9zegg/